# Script is getting the prefab's default data?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using Unity. When instantiating a new gameObjectA with ScriptA, I access gameObjectB's script (ScriptB) while doing so. The thing is, I can only use the prefab of gameObjectB, instead of an already instantiated gameObjectB. For example -

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ScriptB scrptB;

    void Start()
    {
        float X = scrptB.IntegerThatIncreasesEveryFrame;

        Debug.Log(X);
    }
```

In every frame that a gameObjectB has been instantiated, I have integer IntegerThatIncreasesEveryFrame (I'll call it ITIEF now) that, of course, adds 1 to itself every frame.

When gameObjectA and ScriptA gets instantiated, I want to use gameObjectB's ScriptB's ITIEF (e.g. 100 after 100 frames after being instantiated).

I have to use a prefab of gameObjectB, though. When gameObjectA gets instantiated, it uses the DEFAULT value of ITIEF (which is zero).

If this makes sense please help!

Comment: `The thing is, I can only use the prefab of gameObjectB, instead of an already instantiated gameObjectB` ... makes little sense to me ... why do you expect the `scriptB` of a prefab doing its thing (incrementing a value every frame) if it is not instantiated ...? You probably rather want to find an instance of the `scriptB` and access its values ...

Comment: @derHugo I can't drag and drop ScriptB into ScriptA in the inspector, if that's what you're asking. I don't know why, but I have to first attach ScriptB onto a GameObject, and then use that GameObject. I can't even drag and drop the GameObject, I have to use a prefab. But when I try to access certain variables, it uses the default data instead of the new (I even used Debug.Log to make sure the data changes).

Comment: No that's not what I meant... Yes, you can not have scene references in a prefab .. what I said was: you want to **find** the reference to the existing instance ... -> whatever script is spawning the `objectA` should know `objectA` and assign it to the newly spawned objects.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the information from an instanced object, you need to have a reference to the object. In your case, you are referencing the prefab, not the instanced one in game.

The reason why you cannot drag the script itself into the Inspector is because a reference needs to reference a script that is instanced. ScriptA cannot make a reference to ScriptB unless ScriptB is instanced into a gameobject. A prefab acts as an instanced object that doesn't 'exist' in the game. If you want a reference to the instanced script that IS in the game, then you need to set the ScriptB variable to be that in-game script.

```
ScriptB instance = GameObject.FindObjectObType<ScriptB>();
```

This line finds the first instanced form of ScriptB.
This only works if there is ONE instance of ScriptB in the game. If there are more, you need to do a more complicated bit of code.

Are there the same amount of ScriptA and ScriptB? Then when they are both first instanced, store ScriptB somewhere, and then update ScriptA with it.

Your question leaves a lot more questions, but I think I've covered most of the solutions. Pretty much, if you have more than one ScriptB instance, then store the one you want to use and then set it on the ScriptA instance. Otherwise, use `FindObjectOfType` to get a single instance.